# extended protocol limited to 65535 parameters - Golang Gorm

Tags: database, postgresql, go, go-gorm

I am using Gorm library in golang to deal with database (postgres operations).

I am doing the below-mentioned query to get some details.

```
query = query.Where("id in ?", ids).Find(&dest)
```

Length of ids will be considerable (more than 100k)

While hitting the query, I am getting the below-mentioned error.

```
extended protocol limited to 65535 parameters
```

- I have tried the [FindInBatches](https://gorm.io/docs/advanced_query.html#FindInBatches) Function, but it's still giving the same error.
- Using for loop with limits and offset is working but consuming too much time.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this will be helpful.

Comment: This will probably never perform well. At any rate, you should pass a single argument that is an array.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Same thing I have done. 

query = query.Where("id in ?", ids).Find(&dest)

Only the array is passed. But its giving the same error only.

Comment: I am talking about a PostgreSQL array, not a Go array. The query must then use `id = ANY (array_value)`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe Yes, That I used. However, I need an optimized solution as the length of this id array will grow randomly.

Comment: What are those ids? Where are you getting them? And, of course, this in no way connected to gorm or any other library

Comment: @PavloGolub these ids we are getting from the deduplication process.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
type User struct {
    ID string
}

totalUsers := make([]*User, 0, len(ids))
max := 65535 - 1 // safe
for i := 0; i < len(ids); i += max {
    m := i + max
    if len(ids) < m {
        m = len(ids)
    }
    var users []*User
    query.Where("id in ?", ids[i:m]).Find(&users)
    totalUsers = append(totalUsers, users...)
}
```

Comment: As I mentioned, we can use this approach but it will lot of time. suppose we have 1 million ids, sequentially querying them consumes a lot of time.